# Minimize space after ^\top

Tags: spacing, matrices

I am using the Math Times Pro package, and like to use the ^\top command for the matrix transpose character.  In the attached image, there seems to be a space before the \beta, which falls after the ^\top - and this seems ugly or "out of place".  Should I remove dead spaces before \beta?  How can I do that?

Lastly, is the transpose character (^\top) too large for its size?   What would be a new command to reduce its size?

[image]

Comment: isn't the usual syntax T for Transpose rather than `\top` ? maybe `x^{\mathsf{T}}` ?

Comment: `\top` is designed to be paired with `\bot` (logical truth and false) or similar concepts in graphs, it is not a letter T

Comment: actually it's better not to put answers in the question post it spoils the site Q&A format, you could post an answer.  Although in fact I cheated in my comment in a way by suggesting a change of symbol for the mathematical context. in other contexts you mught really want `^\top` and there you might need to adjust with some negative space

Answer (score 1):

Per David Carlisle's comment, yes the x^{\mathsf{T}} is much better -- see attached image.  You're also right that the T doesn't seem to be a Roman "T".

[image]